# Is there something more standard for handling "this" without making "that" reference to "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here:

```
App.prototype.binds = function(){
    var that = this;
    $('.postlist li').live('click', function(){ that.selectPost(this);} );
}

App.prototype.selectPost = function(){
    this.function();
}
```

I am creating a reference of "this" as "that" in my binds function so in my selectPost(), I can use "this" to reference the App object instead of the list item.

Is there a more graceful/standard solution to this instead of using "that"?

---

**With the Answer, my code becomes:**

```
App.prototype.binds = function(){
    $('.postlist li').live('click', $.proxy(this.selectPost, this) );
}

App.prototype.selectPost = function(e){
    this.function(); // function in App

    var itemClicked = e.currentTarget; //or
    var $itemClicked = $(e.currentTarget); 
}
```

Comment: *that* is the standard. (Or *self*, or *$this*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind the functions in constructor or just in time:

In constructor

```
function App() {
    this.selectPost = this.selectPost.bind( this );
                   //$.proxy( this.selectPost, this ) in jQuery
}

App.prototype.binds = function(){
    $('.postlist li').live('click', this.selectPost ); //Already bound in constructor
}
```

Just in time:

```
App.prototype.binds = function(){
    $('.postlist li').live('click', this.selectPost.bind( this ));
                                    //$.proxy( this.selectPost, this ) in jQuery
}
```

Note that [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is only supported in newer browsers, jQuery has [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that should be preferred.

I have opened a feature request in jQuery that has been accepted http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12031. It will make this easier when using jQuery events.

Note that there is a common misunderstanding that the `e.target` will be same as normal `this` in a jQuery event handler. It is actually [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/). So now that `this` refers to the instance and not the element, you can get the elemet through `e.currentTarget`.